# Why is JQuery not 'finding' appended divs?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function that appends some HTML to a section within a form when a button is clicked using this snippet:

```
function add_series() {
    $(document).on("click", "a.add-another-series", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the containing div that we will append the retrieved HTML to
        $container = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();

        // Get the HTML via ajax and append it to the containing div
        $.get('ajax/add-series/' + study_number + '/' + series_number, function(data){
            $container.append(data);
        });
     });
}
```

Here is the (cut-down) HTML structure that is returned to the calling function via AJAX (CAPS indicates this text is a variable):

```
<div class="series" data-study-number="STUDY_NUMBER" data-series-number="SERIES_NUMBER">        
    <h4>series SERIES_NUMBER</h4>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="RANDOM_ID" class="small-12 columns large-centered uploader">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>                          
</div>
```

This works fine and shows up on the page as expected.

What I need to do is grab the div with id=RANDOM_ID from within the first function (the 'on click' one at the beginning of this question). To test, I tried to grab all of the .series divs with the following selector:

```
$series_divs = $('.study[data-study-number="' + STUDY_NUMBER + '"]').find('.content').find('.series');
```

This only seems to return the .series divs that existed before the .append() call. It doesn't return the one I just appended. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Is the `STUDY_NUMBER` the same for both `.study` classed divs?

Comment: can you try using $series_divs = $('.study[data-study-number="' + STUDY_NUMBER + '"]').find('.content .series');

Comment: if you paste a fiddle we could probably help you better. Alot of information is missing and the setup on this is excruciating. It also appear that everytime you add a series you will be appending a new listener to document, so its going to run many times over and over the more you click it. (I don't think that is what you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.add-another-series", function(e) {
    var $container = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();

    e.preventDefault();

    $.get('ajax/add-series/' + study_number + '/' + series_number)
    .then(function(data){
        var $data = $(data),
            id = $data.find(".row div").attr("id");

        $container.append($data);

        // Now something with id. Maybe call a function with it?
    });
});
```

Notes

- What is the purpose of the `function add_series()`? There isn't a lot of use in a function that contains an event handler, so I've removed it.
- You forgot to `var` your variables.
- Instead of `.parent().parent().parent().parent()`, try to work with `.closest()`.
- You don't need to chain your `.find()` calls. `.find('.content').find('.series')` is equivalent to `find('.content .series')`.
- Where do `study_number` and `series_number` come from?

Comment: Grabbing the id within the get function worked great. I'm new to JQuery and have removed the function containing an event handler (it still works as expected). I have replaced the multiple .parent() and .find() calls with your suggestions as they also work perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: For completion, study_number and series_number are predeclared variables higher up the script

Comment: As a general rule: You should avoid global state where you can. That's the same reason why using `var` is so important. Every variable declared without `var` is global, independent of *where* it was declared (try it).

Comment: Also, the switch from a success callback you pass to `.get()` to using `.then()` allows you to easily append `.fail()` and `.always()` callbacks that handle errors or do housekeeping tasks.  See http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/